# Can't access ip 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, python, ip

I am am coding Python (Flask) on Windows 8. To expose a web-app to outside, I have in the past set host=0.0.0.0

Since I have a upgraded and/or installed Hyper-V with Internet access, I am unable to connect to Flask web app using

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000.
```

I have tried shutting down Windows Firewall to no avail.

This is the error:

```
This webpage is not available
The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:5000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 108 (net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID): Unknown error.
```

I also find it curious that I although the app is running at 0.0.0.0, I CAN get to it via localhost/127.0.0.1.

How can I open/enable access to 0.0.0.0?

```
>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 40...c8 60 00 cb fc 55 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
 18...94 db c9 8a c1 c5 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
 15...96 db c9 ac 27 c1 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 14...94 db c9 ac 27 c1 ......Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
 12...c8 60 00 cc 03 5e ......Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.143     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.143    276
    192.168.1.143  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.143    276
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.143    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.143    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.143    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I also find it curious that I although the app is running at 0.0.0.0,
>    I CAN get to it via localhost/127.0.0.1.

That is because the app is not running at 0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0 is just a notation used for 'all IPs, from whereever`.

If the app is running on your own desktop then you can access it via:

- Local host, IP v4 (aka 127.0.0.1)
- Local host, IP v6 (aka ::1).
- The IP on your NIC( in your case: 192.168.1.143 ), assuming you set those to allowed. This is usually done by setting allowed to 0.0.0.0. (aka allow from anywhere).

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0 is typically the outside world, or the internet, hence the route from your gateway to 0.0.0.0  Have you tried setting the host web app to your externally facing IP (go to IPChicken.com)?  Most routers have the default route of IP 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 as the route out of your network to internet.  It means all address's and all subnets.

Comment: Let me wipe the egg off of my face!!! I had a setting in settings.py:
`SERVER_NAME         = 'localhost:5000'` that needed to be reset to 0.0.0.0!!!!!
So sorry for the dumb post! :(